# Unable to git pull with ssh, even with properly configured ssh key

Tags: ssh, git, sshd, github

Long short story, when I try to `git pull`,  the following error is showing :

```
$ git pull
key_from_blob: remaining bytes in key blob 36
key_to_blob: unsupported key type 9
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Of course, I checked that:

- My ssh key is correctly configured
- The remote repository exists
- The remote branch exist
- The remote repository set is the right one
- The remote branch set is the right one
- The repository isn't in a organisation where I didn't configure SSO

What I tried:

- Upgrade my distro (raspbian) to the lastest version
- Update my packages
- Re-create/add a ssh key
- Set my sshd configuration to the default parameters

While re-starting my system between each manipulations, and re-create/add a ssh key between each manipulations if it didn't work.

A strange thing is that when I reboot, the two first lines

```
key_from_blob: remaining bytes in key blob 36
key_to_blob: unsupported key type 9
```

are gone, but re-creating a new ssh key make them re-appear. Anyways, that doesn't fix my main problem : I'm unable to `git pull`.

Comment: How are you generating your ssh keys?

Comment: @Ambidextrous I'm simply following the github docs, like I always did.
`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my_email"`
`eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519`
`cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`
Then I copy the output of the last command and add it in github -> settings -> SSH keys, and I checks that the SSO of the added key is enabled for each orgnizations I'm in.

Comment: Add the output of `ssh -vvv git@github.com` please (or if you're using GitHub Enterprise, substitute `github.com` with whatever the domain for your enterprise server is)

Comment: @muru sorry but I can't, I gave up yesterday, I reset my computer and my problem is gone.